Erase columns from another worksheet
I need to analyze information in an array.
There are two worksheets, "CleanDATA" and "iTOAcolumns".
In "iTOAcolumns" there is a table that contains three columns: how we named the column, the letter (A, B, C, ..., AF, AG, etc.) and a "Keep" column that can be blank or have an X (meaning that we keep that item). That array gets its information from the table in "iTOAcolumns" that determines which columns from "CleanDATA" are deleted.
When you run the macro, the columns that are blank are to be deleted (from the CleanDATA worksheet) and moved to the left to leave no spaces between columns. I want to use an array because I don't want to move between sheets anymore.
Sub Macro6()

' Macro6 Macro

Dim DirArray As Variant
Dim curCOL As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim targetSheet As Worksheet

' Set target sheet
Set targetSheet = Sheets("iTOAcolumns")  ' Replace with your actual sheet name if different

DirArray = targetSheet.Range("KEEPcols").Value  ' Get values from KEEPcols in iTOAcolumns sheet

' Loop through each element in the DirArray
For i = LBound(DirArray, 1) To UBound(DirArray, 1) Step 1

    curCOL = DirArray(i, 1)  ' Get the column letter from the array

    ' Check if the column exists
    If Columns(curCOL).Count > 0 Then

        ' Go to the cell below in column D (assuming criteria)
        targetSheet.Cells(i + 1, 4).Select  ' Select the cell for checking

        ' Check if the cell to the right is empty
        If ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "" Then

            ' Delete the column using the column letter from the array
            Columns(curCOL).EntireColumn.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
        End If
    End If

Next i

End Sub

When reviewing the code using F8, the macro does go through the list, but does not delete any of the desired columns. I don't know if the bounds are incorrect or if the loop is incorrect.
Also, the iTOAcolumn list is listed in ascending order, AJ, AI, AH... first, then C, B, A, last.

You can use Match and the column header:
Sub Macro6()

    Dim i As Long, DirArray As Variant
    Dim infoSheet As Worksheet, dataSheet As Worksheet, m
    
    Set dataSheet = ActiveSheet 'or specific named sheet
    Set infoSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("iTOAcolumns")
    'read all 3 columns to an array: adjust range as needed...
    DirArray = infoSheet.Range("A2:C" & infoSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Value
    
    For i = LBound(DirArray, 1) To UBound(DirArray, 1)
        If Len(DirArray(i, 3)) = 0 Then 'remove this col?
            m = Application.Match(DirArray(i, 1), dataSheet.Rows(1), 0) 'try to match col header
            If Not IsError(m) Then  'if no match then m will be an error value
                dataSheet.Columns(m).Delete
            End If   'matched header
        End If       'a column to delete
    Next i
End Sub


It reads all 3 columns of info from your configuration sheet "iTOAcolumns"  and searches row1 of the "data" sheet for each of the headers in col1 of that configuration table where the "keep" column is blank.  If it finds the column header, it deletes the column.

Delete Columns by Given Column Strings (Headings)
Issues

This is a dangerous operation i.e. you mustn't run it more than once hence the final message box informing that the code has run is crucial.
A safer way would be to have a list of column titles and use Application.Match to attempt to reference each column as illustrated in Tim William's answer. Then you can run the code any number of times but the columns will be deleted only once, in the first run.
To make it more dynamic, don't use a named range but reference the range with the End property also illustrated in Tim William's answer.

Assumptions

The code is in the workbook (ThisWorkbook) containing the sheets.
The single-column range named KeepCols contains the column strings (headings) e.g. A,B,C...AA,AB....
Adjacent to the right is a column with blanks and Xes.

Sub DeleteColumns()
    
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Delete Columns"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Lookup
    Dim lws As Worksheet: Set lws = wb.Sheets("iTOAcolumns")
    Dim lrg As Range: Set lrg = lws.Range("KeepCols")
    Dim cData() As Variant: cData = lrg.Value ' column string
    Dim bData() As Variant: bData = lrg.Offset(, 1).Value ' blank or not
    
    ' Target
    Dim tws As Worksheet: Set tws = wb.Sheets("CleanData")
    
    ' Loop through the rows of the lookup array and check if the value is blank.
    ' If so, combine the target column into a unioned range that will later
    ' be deleted in one go.
    
    Dim turg As Range, tcrg As Range, sr As Long, IsColumnFound As Boolean
    
    For sr = 1 To UBound(bData, 1)
        If Len(CStr(bData(sr, 1))) = 0 Then ' blank value; delete!
            On Error Resume Next ' prevent error if invalid column string
                Set tcrg = tws.Columns(cData(sr, 1))
            On Error GoTo 0
            If Not tcrg Is Nothing Then ' valid column string
                If IsColumnFound Then
                    Set turg = Union(turg, tcrg)
                Else
                    Set turg = tcrg
                    IsColumnFound = True
                End If
                Set tcrg = Nothing ' reset for the next iteration
            'Else ' invalid columns string; do nothing
            End If
        'Else ' not blank value; keep!
        End If
    Next sr
                
    ' Check if no columns to delete.
    If Not IsColumnFound Then
        MsgBox "No columns to delete!", vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Delete columns.
    turg.Delete Shift:=xlShiftToLeft
    
    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "Columns deleted.", vbInformation, PROC_TITLE

End Sub

